# Controller instance variable not accessible in helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, actioncontroller

I've been messing with my `ApplicationController` and somehow broke something. My helper `ApplicationHelper::current_settings` serializes `@user` so that my JS app can load the current user's data. But suddenly:

```
undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
at `@user.id` in app/helpers/application_helper.rb, line 5
```

However, in my better_errors console, I can see that the variable is set on the controller, just not accessible in the current context:

```
>> @user
=> nil
>> controller.instance_variable_get("@user")
=> #<Person id: 1, ...>
>> instance_variable_get("@user")
=> nil
```

I'm setting `@organization` the same way, and it's there:

```
>> @organization
=> #<Organization id: 1 ... >
```

But for some reason, no sign of `@user`!

Here's the helper:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def current_settings
    {
      person: {
        id: @user.id,
        name: @user.to_s
      }
    }.to_json.html_safe
  end
end
```

And in the controller, it's like:

```
before_filter :load_user

def load_user
  @user = Person.where(some_query).first
end
```

Any ideas?? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got it. I was loading organization and user in sequence, but my organization load was returning `nil`, so `load_user` wasn't called:

```
before_filter :authorize

def authorize
  load_organization && load_user
end
```

since `load_organization` was returning `nil`, it didn't kill the controller action chain (like returning `false` would have done) but it also prevented `load_user` from being called. Derp!